# CentOS Minimal + GUI; How to ensure GUI packages are installed from USB rather than from YUM repos?

Tags: linux, usb, installation, centos

I downloaded the CentOS Minimal `.iso` file from CentOS' web site and then created a USB drive via some tool by Fedora, I believe.

I booted up the PC and installed CentOS Minimal, it was flawless, no errors.

Then I simply ran

```
ifup eth0
```

which activates my ethernet internet. Then I ran

```
yum -y groupinstall "Desktop" "Desktop Platform" "X Window System" "Fonts"
```

but it took a long time to download and install, as it was like close to 470+ packages.

Is it possible to somehow store all these packages to a folder or something in the same USB so I do not have to resort to downloading them if I do a reinstall?

How can this be done?

Comment: The easiest way is not to start with the 'minimal' iso.

Answer (score 0):

- Make a full backup of your system and restore it over a new minimal installation.
- Duplicate your disk by using dd:

  ```
  dd if=/dev/sda | gzip -c  > /sda_image.img.gz
  ```

  And restore it to a new disk if needed

  ```
  gunzip -c /sda_image.img.gz | dd of=/dev/sda
  ```

DD images your disk and it is the best way to backup your system configuration